# Appending string to list number of times equal to number in separate list

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

Having a bit of trouble getting this to work. Apologies if the question is poorly formatted (or if the problem is stupidly simple). Novice Python programmer :P

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Step 1: Identify lists of strings matching criteria

Step 2: Append specific string from lists to a new list

Step 3: Do step 2 a number of times equal to an integer in a separate list
```

A little confusing, I know. Hopefully my code helps explain it a little better:

```
# Create Lists
trial_length = [2570, 2573, 2575, 2565, 2569, 2499, 2565, 2559, 2563, 2491, 
                2574, 2560, 2566, 2572, 2567, 2507, 2571, 2560, 2573, 2570]
condition = []

# Access file that I'm parsing
foo = open('test.asc','rw+')
for line in foo:
    # Turn lines of file into individual lists
    new_line = line.split()
    # Select relevant lines
    if len(new_line)==6:
        if new_line[4]=='TEST':
            # Append new_line to "condition" a number of times 
            # equal to integer in "trial_length"
            for n in trial_length:
                for t in range(0,n):
                    condition.append(new_line)
```

Of course, I realize now that this is incorrect. For the first number in "trial_length", for example, it appends new_line to "condition" 2570 times and then repeats that process 20 times. I think this is simply an error in my coding logic. What am I missing here?

EDIT:

Should have posted this earlier. My desired end result would be "TEST" appended to "condition" 2570 times + 2573 times +...etc. With this current code, it's being appended 1,022,980 times, which is the sum of the numbers in "trial_length" * 20.

The reason that I'm doing this is that the actual file I'm using is composed of the results from an experiment. The experiment has 20 trials, each of which were run under one of two conditions: "Congruent" or "Incongruent". Each trial runs a different length (e.g. 2570 seconds, 2573 seconds, etc.). For each line in a trial, I want to append the correct condition in a separate column. Therefore, I'm creating a list with the strings "Congruent" and "Incongruent" appended in the correct amount and order.

So in short, my list would look like this:

```
condition = ['Congruent' * 2570 times, 'Incongruent' * 2573 times, 
             'Incongruent' * 2575 times,...etc.].
```

The reason I didn't mention this earlier was that I wanted to reduce the problem to what I thought was its simplest form, which is appending a string to a list a number of times equal to an integer in a separate list.

EDIT 2:

In response to 2rs2rt, my input file is an ASCII/ASCE file that's essentially just lines of strings. For example, italicized and bolded is one of the lines that I'm targeting:

```
EFIX R   718603 719256  654   285.0   370.0    1105
719257    288.6   370.8  1064.0 ...
END 719258  SAMPLES EVENTS  RES   29.38   28.94
INPUT   719259  127
***MSG  719276 !V TRIAL_VAR CONGRUENT 331***
MSG 719277 !V TRIAL_VAR direction 20
MSG 719278 TRIAL_RESULT 0
MSG 719279 UPDATE_JITTER_1
MSG 719283 -5 INSTRUCTIONS
MSG 719649 0 JITTER
MSG 719649 TRIALID 2
MSG 719665 RECCFG CR 1000 2 1 R
MSG 719665 ELCLCFG MTABLER
MSG 719665 GAZE_COORDS 0.00 0.00 1023.00 767.00
MSG 719665 THRESHOLDS R 105 226
MSG 719665 ELCL_PROC CENTROID (3)
MSG 719665 ELCL_PCR_PARAM 5 3.0
```

Out of all of those lines, I'm selecting the ones that have "Congruent" or "Incongruent" in them. Now here are examples of lines of the actual data:

```
719667    296.3   380.1  1165.0 ...
719668    296.0   379.9  1163.0 ...
719669    296.2   379.7  1161.0 ...
719670    296.5   379.3  1159.0 ...
719671    296.7   379.0  1160.0 ...
719672    296.9   378.8  1160.0 ...
```

Now imagine these lines going on 2570 times, 2573 times, etc. If "Congruent" is identified as the condition variable at the end of these lines (marked by the "END  719258  SAMPLES EVENTS  RES   29.38   28.94" line), then append "Congruent" to this new list a number of times equal to the length of the trial. If "Incongruent", append "Incongruent" that number of times.

Comment: What does your desired end result look like?

Comment: Does `open('test.asc','rw+')` work for you? I mean, using `'rw+'`.

Comment: The first time you find a line that meets your conditions, how many instances of new_line do you want to append to condition?  Say ```trial_length = [1, 2, 3]``` and ```new_line = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'TEST', 'e']``` - what should condition look like?

Comment: Could you please give some example of what you are expecting in `contition` when the code ran completly?

Comment: How do you determine whether to append `'Congruent'` versus `'Incongruent'`? I bet I could solve this if you let me know what your input file looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter), since you want to do the `n` append calls with different lines. Sounds like the first `'TEST'` line should use `trial_length[0]`, the second should use `trial_length[1]`, and so forth.

```
currLength = iter(trial_length)
with open('test.asc','rw+') as foo:
    for line in foo:
        # Turn lines of file into individual lists
        new_line = line.split()
        # Select relevant lines
        if len(new_line)==6 and new_line[4]=='TEST':
            # Append new_line to "condition" a number of times 
            # equal to integer in "trial_length"
            try:
                n = next(currLength)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            for t in range(0,n):
                condition.append(new_line)
```

This will make it so that you use a new element from `trial_length` each time you read a `'TEST'` line. `next()` asks the iterator to give you the next element in the sequence. When you run out of elements, calling `next()` throws a `StopIteration` exception.

This is actually how `for` loops work. They rely on the internal method [`__iter__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter).

*You could use `enumerate()` if you didn't need to check the line for certain conditions, too.*

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I'll be sure to upvote you when I have enough reputation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the criteria is for selecting the number from the `trial_length` list. But the reason, it is repeating 20 times after the 2570 times is because there are 20 elements in the `trial_length` array.

In the step 3 of the problem statement, you mention `Do step 2 a number of times equal to an integer in a separate list`. What is the criteria to select this integer? If there is a criteria then replace your `for n in trial_length:` with that logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick an item el from trial_length based on some condition. You can then do

```
for t in range(el):
    condition.append(new_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid calling append N times by just using something like:

```
condition.extend(value for i in xrange(N))
```

Answer (score -1):

It does not append 20 Times
It appends new_line 2570 + 2573 + .... + 2573 + 2570 (51149) times to the condition
Do you simply want it to be 2570 times and not the rest

```
for t in range(trial_length[0]):
    condition.append(new_line)
```

Comment: Obviously OP is looking to use the other numbers in `trial_length`.